# Sending HTML5 canvas data (rgba) to asm.js. Type of arrays in c++ / javascript

Tags: c++, html, canvas, emscripten, asm.js

I have a c++ exported function (compiled with emscripten) that receives an unsigned char* array with pixel data.

What I want to do is take an image from HTML5 canvas and send it to this function.
HTML canvas getImageData() method returns a uint8ClampedArray.

I am looking for a way to pass that data. Does anyone have a solution to this?